# jQuery - Why is my jquery hide/show code not working

Tags: jquery

I have this painfully simple jquery code, or so I thought, but it doesn't function as expcted

All i want is, **if value selected from dropdown = 'Poster', hide all the fieldsets, then show the one(s) I select.  If value selected from dropdown = 'Logo', hide all the fieldsets, then show the one(s) I select and so on**. Simple I know, but the fieldsets will not always hide as they should.

For example, if I select '**Logo**' from the down, only **one** fieldset should display, this works, then if I select '**booklet**', several field-sets should display and this works, but if I go back and select logo again, all the field-sets remain instead of hiding all and then showing on the one needed for the project type 'Logo'.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?  **Note**:  On change of project type dropdown field, the projectTypeChange() is called

```
function projectTypeChange()
{
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('fieldset#section-960', 'fieldset#section-961', 'fieldset#section-962', 'fieldset#section-964', 'fieldset#section-967').hide();
        var dropVal = $('select#6211').val();

       if(dropVal ==  "Poster")
           {
              $('fieldset#section-960', 'fieldset#section-961', 'fieldset#section-962', 'fieldset#section-964', 'fieldset#section-967').hide();
              $('fieldset#section-960').show(); 
              $('fieldset#section-961').show(); 
              $('fieldset#section-967').show(); 
              $('fieldset#section-962').show(); 
           }
       if(dropVal ==  "Booklet")
           {
              $('fieldset#section-960', 'fieldset#section-961', 'fieldset#section-962', 'fieldset#section-964', 'fieldset#section-967').hide();
              $('fieldset#section-960').show(); 
              $('fieldset#section-961').show(); 
              $('fieldset#section-967').show(); 
              $('fieldset#section-962').show(); 
              $('fieldset#section-964').show(); 
           }
       if(dropVal ==  "Logo")
           {
              $('fieldset#section-960', 'fieldset#section-961', 'fieldset#section-962', 'fieldset#section-964', 'fieldset#section-967').hide();
              $('fieldset#section-962').show(); 
           }

        });
}
```

Comment: perhaps you could make a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ where we could see the problem in action?

Comment: have you used `console.log` within that function to see if those conditional statements are firing? Have you verified that dropVal is spitting back the values with a upper case letter? also the $(document).ready function should be outside of this projectTypeChange function..

Comment: A demo would be really helpful here.  If you are unable to provide a demo the html would be useful too.

Answer (score 1):

Because you use

`$(document).ready(function() { });`

This is typically used to do something right after the document has loaded.
Once your dropdown box changes, your document has loaded a while ago, and everything within

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    // this part here

 });
```

Will not execute.

The simple solution : remove `$(document).ready(function() {` (and its closing bracket `});` from your event handler, it should not be in there in the first place.
Put it somewhere outside the event handler.

Your corrected code should read :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('fieldset#section-960', 'fieldset#section-961', 'fieldset#section-962', 'fieldset#section-964','fieldset#section-967').hide();
});

function projectTypeChange()
{
        var dropVal = $('select#6211').val();

       if(dropVal ==  "Poster")
           {
              $('fieldset#section-960', 'fieldset#section-961', 'fieldset#section-962', 'fieldset#section-964', 'fieldset#section-967').hide();
              $('fieldset#section-960').show(); 
              $('fieldset#section-961').show(); 
              $('fieldset#section-967').show(); 
              $('fieldset#section-962').show(); 
           }
       if(dropVal ==  "Booklet")
           {
              $('fieldset#section-960', 'fieldset#section-961', 'fieldset#section-962', 'fieldset#section-964', 'fieldset#section-967').hide();
              $('fieldset#section-960').show(); 
              $('fieldset#section-961').show(); 
              $('fieldset#section-967').show(); 
              $('fieldset#section-962').show(); 
              $('fieldset#section-964').show(); 
           }
       if(dropVal ==  "Logo")
           {
              $('fieldset#section-960', 'fieldset#section-961', 'fieldset#section-962', 'fieldset#section-964', 'fieldset#section-967').hide();
              $('fieldset#section-962').show(); 
           }


}
```

Comment: fieldset can be removed from selectors too because id are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score -1):

ok, shoot me now.  I found it - always seems to happen, **after**, I have asked for help.

the problem was my quotes.

**I had:**
$('fieldset#section-960', 'fieldset#section-961', 'fieldset#section-962', 'fieldset#section-964', 'fieldset#section-967').hide();

**when it should have been:**
$('fieldset#section-960, fieldset#section-961, fieldset#section-962, fieldset#section-964, fieldset#section-967').hide();

quotes at end, NOT around each.  I will leave this one up, to hopefully prevent someone else from feeling as silly as I do.  Thanks for all your input.